# Difference between Indexers and Object array?

Tags: c#

Just now i read indexers in msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx

I got confusion ,because indexers look like a object array on that example.Please tell me the difference between  **Indexers** and **Object array**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indexers are properties that let you provide an array-like interface to your class. It doesn't mean your object is an array.

Comment: A better example would be something that's more obviously not an array, such as a dictionary.

Comment: @Rawling - The comment you were responding to (that mentioned `System.String` as an example) seems to have been deleted anyway.

Comment: @Martin Well, I still like my example :p

Comment: If C# supported extended properties (and extended indexers), it would be possible to add an indexer to an integer, so that 25[2] would return the 2nd prime factor of 25.